# Out of M experiments, how often does Index i get picked last

Tags: python

This may be a pretty simple question but I can't seem to understand a way to answer it, in addition I am very fresh as a Python programmer. Would appreciate a guiding hand.

The question is as follows: I have an array of n+1 items, the experiment begins at index 0. At a probability of .5 I can go either right or left modulo n+1. The index wins if he was picked last. Overall I have M experiments.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def simulate_game( n, m ):
    bin = [0] * (n + 1)
    results = [0] * (n + 1)
    while m != 0:
        current = 0
        for i in bin:
            bin[i] = False
        while (all(bin) == 0):
            bin[current] = 1
            randnum = random.randint(0, 1)
            if randnum == 1:
                current += 1
                if current > 0:
                    current = (current % (n+1))
            elif randnum == 0:
                current -= 1
                if current < 0:
                    current = (current % (n+1))
        results[current] += 1
        m -= 1
    for x in results:
        print(x)
    return results

# Do not change anything below this line!
def main():
    L = simulate_game( 2, 10 )
    plt.plot( L, 'bo', L,'k' )
    plt.axis( [0,2,0.5*min(L[1:]),1.5*max(L)] )
    plt.xlabel('Players')
    plt.ylabel('Wins')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output I receive for n=5 and m=100 is unrealistic at:
44
0
55
1
0
0

Been trying to debug but am not coming to a problem in the code, would appreciate an a tip in the right direction because I'm slowly becoming more and more frustrated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain the jumps (*At a probability of .5 I can go either right or left modulo n+1*) a bit better?

Comment: What I meant was that at a probability of 0.5 I can move my index (which began at 0) to either index 1 or index -1 (n)

Comment: so always to neighboring elements, no bigger jumps.

Comment: Exactly only +-1

Comment: In my opinion, there are two parameters of the experiment (beyond the number of indices available): how often to advance from initial index 0 to arrive at the final position and how often to execute the experiment. What corresponds to your *M* and what is the other?

Comment: M is how often to execute the experiment, and I used a while loop whose stopping condition is when the entire binary array is comprised out of ones (the experiment has ended).

Comment: @TomerBarzilay: This should be in the question (so you should edit it) and I have to to admit, that it  destroyed my idea of what your problem is. It also appears not to be consistent with the code, since there `results[current] += 1` does not really stop at one.